# Hadoop Configuration for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: hadoop, raspberry-pi2

I finally have got my Hadoop 2.6 running on rasbian on a RB Pi 2. I'm now going to tune it before deploying another node.

My current config is the pretty much default from a tutorial I've found on :
http://nextgenhadoop.blogspot.pt/2013/10/steps-to-install-hadoop-220-stable.html
And some troubleshooting tips from stackoverflow.

Due to the RAM available and CPU the Pi2 has, I'm sure there will be a 'ideal' config to it, I've been messing with yarn-site.xml adding and removing memory in a way that seems logical to me, but the Pi doesnt agree.

Right now I have 1 node, with '8 vcores' and '8GB' of ram. This can't of course be true

Can anyone share their config with me ?

Comment: What do you mean by this question? Why would you set `8 GB` of memory when the Raspberry PI 2 has only `1 GB`?
Another question is why would you run Hadoop on Raspberry PI (especially when you have just one node)? Makes no sense. It just won't work.

Comment: Thats exactly the point. I'm doing this only for fun, I dont know where to set the number of cores and max ram in Haddop 2.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

These two propeties from `yarn-site.xml` file are relevant to nodemanager resources:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
    <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
</property>
```

You can find more in [Hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to trim it down, here is my congig, please feel free to comment on them. thanks

my yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>128</value>
    <description>Minimum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>768</value>
    <description>Maximum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests lower than this won't take effect, and the specified value will get allocated the minimum.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests higher than this won't take effect, and will get capped to this value.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>768</value>
    <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
</property>
```

and my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
</property>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>hadoopi00:54311</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>768</value>
  </property>
<property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx384m</value>
</property>
<property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx384m</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```